# R knnImpute not working

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the following code as an example:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(100:104,NaN,106:110),y=c(200:204,NaN,206:210))
s = preProcess(df,method="knnImpute")
```

When I use the predict function using the following code:

```
pre = predict(s,df)
```

R just crashes and I have to restart.

What is wrong with the code above?  Also, do you need 2 columns for knnImpute to work?

Comment: Please provide the name of the package the functions are coming from.

Comment: Hello Pascal, Sorry.  The package is caret. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gregory Jefferis, who maintains the package cleared the mystery: preprocessing with knnImpute silently removes any columns containing NA values, so both your variables x and y are lost before predict(). Here is an example that works without crashing. The trick is to have a few more related columns without NAs.

```
x=rnorm(100); y=rnorm(100)
z1 = x+2*y + rnorm(100,sd=0.1)
z2 = 3*x+2 + rnorm(100,sd=0.3)
z2 = 2*y+8 + rnorm(100,sd=0.3)
df = data.frame(x,y,z1,z2)
head(df)
df[25, 1] = NA
df[50, 2] = NA
xform = preProcess(df, method="knnImpute")
predict(xform, df)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Raja for the reply. That helps. So if I understand correctly, z1,z2 above are just dummy variables.